# CSS Floating trouble

Tags: css, css-float

Hi
I have this really strange error....
I have two elements: paragraph and a link with an image inside of it. 
Paragraph overlaps the link this results in that the link becomes ineffective... 
How fix this? 
Thanks in advance ;)

EDIT: Instead I will give you a link to mi site : http://e-skaitykla.lt/ . Try the posts images are the links and I can press them only in Opera.

FIX: There was misunderstanding in positioning types. P was set to have relative positioning. When I added the same thing to A tag all fixed

Thanks everybody who tried to help ;)

Comment: An example of the markup might help illustrate your problem.

Comment: if you can post a demo of your problem on-line, I can recommend both [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) or [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this, that would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Absent actual code, I'd guess that you're either positioning the paragraph and the link absolutely or you're floating stuff inside the paragraph and the browser isn't correctly calculating the dimensions of the elements.  Strip off any CSS and add declarations back one at a time to debug.